# Which is the correct gallery app in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, android-gallery

I am trying to understand the google's implementation of the android image gallery from https://android.googlesource.com/ 
But I see there are 3 apps :
Gallery, Gallery2, Gallery3D. 
What is the difference between these three? Which is the right gallery AOSP app I should refer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's related to your target Android version - on CyanogenMod 11 (KitKat) you get Gallery2, on 13 (Marshmallow) you get Gallery3D